# Correctly sharing variables between threads (.NET/VB.NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, synchronization

I've been reading a lot of various blogs and StackOverflow questions to try to find an answer to my question and at the end I could not find anything so I thought to ask the question myself.

I am building an application where I have a long running worker threads which perform some operations and places some results into variables during its run. The worker thread is constantly working and is constantly producing some results whereby I am only interested in the 'current' value of the result. At some point another thread will get the 'current' result of the worker thread run and do something with it.

A simple implementation of such worker thread can be done like this:

```
Public Class Worker

    Private _result As DateTimeOffset?

    Public ReadOnly Property Result As DateTimeOffset?
        Get
            Return _result
        End Get
    End Property


    Public Sub ThreadMethod()
        ' Do something
        _result = x
        ' .
        ' .
        _result = y
        ' .
        ' .
        ' etc
    End Sub

End Class
```

Now lets say I have I a consumer which wants to consume the result:

```
Public Class Consumer

    Private _worker As Worker

    Public Sub Consume()
        Dim result As DateTimeOffset?
        While True
            ' Do some work on your own
            ' .
            ' .
            ' Get current result
            result = _worker.Result
            ' Do something with result

        End While
    End Sub

End Class
```

As far as I have understood how compilers work it seems logical that the compiler could make the `Property Result` inline and then optimize away the `_result` variable into a register and just read the same value over and over again.
In C# I could mark the result as `volatile` and this (I think) would prevent such optimization but the keyword does not exist in VB.NET.
The closest solution I could come up with is to use `Volatile.Write` and `Volatile.Read` methods. However those methods can not be used with `Nullable(Of DateTimeOffset)`.

Note 1: Although this question seems to be related to weak/strong memory model and usage of memory barriers I do not believe that they have any impact in this scenario. That being said if somebody states that `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` would force the read/write to be from memory that it is also a good enough solution for me.

Note 2: I am aware that there are other ways to solve the problem but I would like to know if the solution is possible (if the problem even exists, I am not even sure about that) for the described scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `Thread.MemoryBarrier` only ensures the order of memory accesses in that thread. What you have is two threads that access the same variable, so you need more protection than that.

The varable is not atomic, so if you don't synchronise the accesses you may end up reading a partially written value. You can make a synchronised getter and setter for the property, and then use the setter in the worker thread to set the value instead of setting the backing variable.

```
Private _result As DateTimeOffset?
Private _sync as New Object()

Public Property Result As DateTimeOffset?
    Get
        SyncLock _sync
            Return _result
        End SyncLock
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value as dateTimeOffset?)
        SyncLock _sync
            _result = Value
        End SyncLock
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Hmm. As I understand your answer it seems that if I have variable types which are not supported with Volatile.Read and Volatile.Write I should always wrap it in lock/unlock.
I assume that variable types supported by Volatile.Read/Write (integer, double, boolean etc) can be read normally? Or am I mistaken and I need to use locking for them as well?

Comment: @TheBlueDog: I forgot to remove the readonly keyword. Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: @dcarapic: You can use `Volatile.Read` and `Volatile.Write` to access variables that are atomic, provided that you use both, i.e. not let the code in the worker thread write directly to the variable. The `Int64` type for example is not guaranteed to be atomic in a 32 bit application, and volatile access doesn't protect against partial writes.